# Finding a character at a specific position of a string

Tags: php

Since I am still new to PHP, I am looking for a way to find out how to get a specific character from a string.

Example:

```
$word = "master";
$length = strlen($word);
$random = rand(1,$length);
```

So let's say the $random value is 3, then I would like to find out what character the third one is, so in this case the character "s". If $random was 2 I would like to know that it's a "a".

I am sure this is really easy, but I tried some substr ideas for nearly an hour now and it always fails.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "it always fails" -- can we see your attempts?

Comment: One thing of note is that the index of the string is zero-based, so if random is 3, you should expect to get 't'

Comment: You can treat a string as if it's an array. `$word[0]` would be **m**.

Comment: I'll bet your substr is right, you probably are just starting from 1 instead of 0. The way you have it, you'll never be able to access $word[0], because your random number starts at 1.

Comment: echo $word[$random]; ....something like that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to grab a portion of a string starting from a point and going length. so example would be:

```
substr('abcde', 1, 1); //returns b
```

In your case:

```
$word = "master";
$length = strlen($word) - 1;
$random = rand(0,$length);
echo substr($word, $random, 1);//echos single char at random pos
```

See it in action [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zfg-qrv)

Comment: As written, this will never hit 'm' and could go out of bounds

Comment: fixed. forget i needed to do length - 1 to prevent OOB

Comment: Thanks so much, this really works great. I played with substr for nearly an hour and the main issue was the offset since I was not aware that I have to start from 0 and not from 1. Thanks again!

Comment: string characters are a 0-based index. first characters are at $str[0] and increment for each character.

Answer (score 15):

You can use your string the same like 0-based index array:

```
$some_string = "apple";
echo $some_string[2];
```

It'll print 'p'.

or, in your case:

```
$word = "master";
$length = strlen($word);
$random = rand(0,$length-1);

echo $word[$random];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simply:

```
$word = "master";
$length = strlen($word);
$random = rand(0,$length-1);

if($word[$random] == 's'){
 echo $word[$random]; 
}
```

Here I used 0 because `$word[0]` is `m` so that we need to subtract one from `strlen($word)` for getting last character `r`

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr`

```
$GetThis = substr($myStr, 5, 5);
```

Just use the same values for the same or different if you want multiple characters

```
$word = "master";
$length = strlen($word);
$random = rand(0,$length-1);
$GetThis = substr($word, $random, $random);
```

As noted in my comment (I overlooked as well) be sure to start your `rand` at `0` to include the beginning of your string since the `m` is at place `0`. If we all overlooked that it wouldn't be random (as random?) now would it :)

Comment: As written, this will never hit 'm' and could go out of bounds

Comment: Also note that the last parameter of substr is the maximum length of the substring to return, not the index you want to end at, so it should probably be 1 in all cases

Comment: If the OP uses your code and echo's `$GetThis`, will get a parse error if there's no closing semi-colon in `$GetThis = substr($word, $random, $random)` --- *Just saying* ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii I should stop just typing stuff in from the top of my head :)

Comment: @sealz I do that too sometimes, but when it comes to the actual "important" stuff, then yeah... can't do that. (LOL) Cheers ;-) (+1) btw - it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$myStr{$random}` to obtain the nth character of the string.

Comment: deprecated - don't use. (Appreciate this is an old answer)