# helpe to convert from java to php

Tags: java, php

I have written a java code and I need help writing it in PHP because I do not have enough experience with PHP

```
public static String mo31385a(String str, String str2, String str3) {
    int length = str.length();
    char[] cArr = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char charAt = str.charAt(i);
        int indexOf = str2.indexOf(charAt);
        if (indexOf < 0) {
            cArr[i] = charAt;
        } else {
            cArr[i] = str3.charAt(indexOf);
        }
    }
    return new String(cArr);
}
```

i want thes function by php plz

Comment: This is not a free code translation service.  If you want someone to write (or translate) some code for you, there are websites where you can hook up with a free-lance coder to to some work ... for money.

Comment: just i want how to written   char charAt = str.charAt(i); with php

Comment: Alternatively ... get experience with PHP by trying to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452024 ... or any PHP tutorial will tell you.

Comment: `just i want how to written char charAt = str.charAt(i); with php`...well why didn't you ask that to begin with? Always ask the question you want to ask rather than a different one :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here:

```
function mo31385a($str, $str2, $str3)
    {
        $cArr = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
        {
            $charAt = $str[$i];
            $indexOf = strpos($str2,$charAt);
            if (!$indexOf)
            {
                $cArr[] = $charAt;
                continue;
            }
            $cArr[] = $str3[$indexOf];  
        }
        return implode("",$cArr);
    }
```